# Expanding some elisp into HTML inside Org

Tags: org-mode, html

I am creating an HTML file containing some notes exported from org mode. I would like to add all images from a folder into the HTML file generated i.e the images should display in the webpage when opened.

Is there a way to insert a bit of local Emacs-Lisp code in the org mode file such that on exporting to HTML, the code block expands to something a sequence of `<img>` tags containing file names from the folder `images`. (I guess I am looking for something like a kind of local macro expansion?)

To be precise I want something like

```
blah blah 
blah blah 


<<< Elisp code that expands to HTML inside Org file>>>

blah blah blah 
blah blah
```

to be converted into

```
blah blah 
blah blah 

<figure>
    <img src="./images/image1.png" width="300px" />
</figure>

<figure>
    <img src="./images/image2.png" width="300px" />
</figure>
.
.
.

<figure>
    <img src="./images/image700.png" width="300px" />
</figure>

blah blah blah 
blah blah
```

Note that I don't want this expanded HTML gunk inside the org mode file itself, but inside the exported HTML file.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this perhaps - I've written the code block in python but you can do it in any language you want:

```
* foo

blah blah blah

#+begin_src python :results output :exports results :var n=700 :wrap export html
  for i in range(1,n+1):
      print('<figure>\n    <img src="./images/image{}.png" width="300px" />\n</figure>\n'.format(i))

#+end_src

blah blah blah
blah blah bla
```

The `:wrap export html` is the important thing: it will wrap the results in

```
#+begin_export html

#+end_export
```

allowing the exporter to just copy them verbatim to the HTML output file.

The `:exports results` header makes sure that the block will be evaluated when you export and will produce the boilerplate, but as long as you are careful *NOT* to evaluate it in the buffer with `C-c C-c` you won't see the results there. If you do evaluate it by mistake, you can get rid of the results with `M-x org-babel-remove-result RET`.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks! It worked. It's great I can use Python for this. Not a big Lisper myself.